# Laravel eloquent query BelngsToMany pivot table

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to write an Eloquent query for a BelongsToMany relationship and where the results return only one distinct result based on the pivot table. See below for example.

Installer:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Installer 1 |
| 2 | Installer 2 |

State:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | State 1 |
| 2 | State 2 |

Pivot:

| Id | State Id | Installer Id | Baseline | Created At |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1.0 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1.2 | 2023-01-02 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1.5 | 2023-01-01 |

So I would like to run the query `$state->installers()->get()` where, using the example above, Installer 1 only returns ID 2 and 3. The reason I do not want ID 1 is because it is an older record by the created at column. Is the only way I can accomplish this is with a join? Not eloquent ORM?

Comment: The scenario you've got here isn't typical for a many-to-many, so it's not likely going to work with Laravel's `belongsToMany` without modification (i.e. sorting by a column on the `pivot` table, and limiting results to the "latest" of each `state_id`). You usually only have each `Installer`/`State` combination _once_, often enforced by a unique composite key using `installer_id` and `state_id`.

Comment: Are you expecting a sql or laravel answer? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Which type of the data you want? we can perform eloquent and as well ORM model query for this operation.

Comment: @MohitNandpal any data type is fine, eloquent or a model query.

Comment: @JonErickson Do you only need data in distinct order from pivot table using state model?

Comment: @MohitNandpal I only need the baseline value from the pivot table and a “name” field from the installer table. Only one distinct record should be pulled from the pivot table based using then created at column to get most recent. So in this example state id 1 should only return, for the installers relationship, pivot id 2 since it is the newest.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question and relationship in Pivot Table and I found this solution:

Try this raw `SQL join` with Eloquent.

```
$state = State::find($stateId); // Replace $stateId with the ID of the state you want to retrieve data for.

$installers = Installer::select('installers.id', 'installers.name')
    ->join('installer_state', 'installers.id', '=', 'installer_state.installer_id')
    ->where('installer_state.state_id', $stateId)
    ->orderBy('installer_state.created_at', 'desc')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

This query will returns the data by `$stateId` where it is firstly check the condition for `$stateId` and get the data in orderBy `created_date` field with `distinct` value.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: This works as long as you are not selecting the baseline column. I need to return the baseline column most importantly - the distinct then no longer works.

Comment: @JonErickson you didn't mention the baseline column in your question. So I was writing the answer as per your query.